# unordered_set<vector<int>> throws "Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor" error

Tags: c++, unordered-set

`unordered_set<vector<int>> my_set;`

I am using xcode for c++ development and I came across a wired error. When I declared a `unordered_set` with the generic of `vector<int>`, I got an error, saying:

> Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of '__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::hash<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator > >, 1>'

I tried `unordered_set<vector<int>>`.

I tried similar stuff like `unordered_set<int>`, `unordered_set<vector<int>*>`, `set<vector<int>>`, and all of them works out fine. What is wrong with `unordered_set<vector<int>>`?

I was a java developer and am transferring to c++ recently. So my logic might still be a little bit of "java"...

Comment: Make sure you look at the full error message. Mine comes with a [descriptive static assertion](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ToK4Pz).

Comment: To be explicit, you need a hash function for `T` in order to use it in `unordered_set<T>`. Clearly `vector<int>` does not have a hash function by default, so you must supply one. All of the collection classes make some requirements on their value types, and this is one example.

Comment: Just calling a template a generic is proof of your Java background. Although the purpose is similar the design is totally different.